# can't change page slug

Tags: slug

I created a page (with slug "page-title" say), then deleted it.

I created a 2nd page with the same title, and it automatically saved itself with a page slug of "page-title-2".

The first page no longer exists, not in the trash either, but I can't rename the 2nd page's slug to "page-title".

How can I do so?

Answer (score 3):

My first guess would have been that the page was in the Trash, but you've said in the OP that it isn't.  So... If you have access to your MySQL database, run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_name = 'page-title'
```

That will return the post that's using the slug.

Comment: My answer was deleted by @toscho, but what I was adding to Shawn's answer was that once you've used the above you can delete that row to start using the slug again.

Answer (score 1):

The page with `page-title` as the slug is still hanging out in the Trash. You will need to delete it there, or change it's slug if you are wanting `page-title-2` to be able to become `page-title`.